# TortoiseSVN shows red ! decorator for folder, but no files within it are marked with "!"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm new to SVN. I'm using the latest version (svn 1.6.9, TortoiseSVN 1.6.7.18415).

Some folders who a red exclamation point next to them. If I drill down, I find a sub folder with ! as well but no *files* within that are marked with ! (all are either a green checkmark or no icon (because they are Ignored (like .exe files) .

What I've tried:

- Cleanup {reported success}
- Add {reports nothing to add. All files  either under version control has been ignored per the .ignore property.
- Commit {succeeds}
- SVNupdate {succeeds}
- Restarted computer.

Some oddities:
-I had a bunch of CVS folders (these files were copied over from a PC that was using CVS but we don't need that version history so I didn't import it into SVN).  I deleted those CVS\ folders and they are showing up (as unversioned files) when I CheckIn.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** Here's what I did that fixed it (based on [Turnkeys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2457430/166848)):

1. Did an SVN>**Commit** and checked all the "non versioned" CVS folders (that I'd deleted),
2. Did an **SVNupdate** and then only one folder was still showing (!).
3. Did an SVN> **CleanUp** and it's all looking good now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It sounds as if those deleted files may have been marked as checked-in at some point and SVN is trying to delete them in the repository when you do the commit.  Are you sure when you do the commit that it's not merely trying to update those files as missing rather than check them in?  If so, go ahead and check them in as deleted by checking them during the commit (they should have a "Text Status" of missing.

Answer (score 9):

I have had this happen right after I have done a check-in.  Even hitting F5 to refresh the window might not refresh the folder decorator.

Possible solutions I've used:

1. Do an update on the folder
2. Close the explorer window and reopen it
3. Open up the Tortoise SVN settings... click Icon Overlays... then change the Status Cache at the top of the right panel to be 'None'.
4. The TSVNCache.exe process caches the status... it might be hung or something.  End process (if you think it's hung).

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a tree conflict on the folder. See the [TortoiseSVN help](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html#tsvn-dug-conflicts-tree) for more information about what they are, and how to resolve them.

Answer (score 1):

See also my answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5904832/277307).

If there are no modifications to the working copy, the shell overlay may just need to be refreshed manually.  You can do this with TortoiseSVN 1.7 and can automate it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have some property changes on the folder.  Also sometimes Tortoise doesn't catch up with the state of directory.  Just wait for a few minutes and look at your folder again.

Also, right click on your folder and select "Check for modifications" or "Commit" it should show you the files that are out of sync with the repository

Answer (score 0):

as soon as you will commit the files that are marked will get deleted by svn.
BEWARE !!

Comment: This should be a comment. It does not answer OP's question