# Tortoisesvn not showing up correct status after commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I was going to ask this in tigris.org, however they have maintenance in their forum.

My environment:
Windows 7 x64, Tortoisesvn latest x64, simple repo.

What I'm doing:
I am adding a new file to repo, then doing SVN Commit. This operation is successful and I can see it in repo from trac or directly.

I expect:
To see that file's icon as green checkmark.

What I have:
I see blue PLUS icon, like I haven't done commit.

However, if I just create any new file in that folder(without any commit or update), the icon is immediately changing to checkmark. What a magic!

I don't expect here anyone to have answer, this might be a bug, but who knows ))

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's just that the pane is not refreshing until another action is done. I have seen this on Windows XP as well. I imagine it's a bug in TortoiseSVN.

Comment: so any workaround to this? Have you experienced on TortoiseSVN 32 or 64 bit version?

Comment: @michael - not that i'm aware of, my solution was to manually refresh if the icon had not changed just to make sure.

Comment: Close and open explorer window. That helps

Answer (score 12):

Cleaning up the project typically corrects the icon.  Right click on the folder and select TortoiseSVN -> Clean up. I suspect this updates the TortoiseSVN cache.  (My environment is also Win 7 x64)

**Update:** In TortoiseSVN 1.7, cleanup now brings up a dialog which includes an explicit option to "Refresh shell overlays."  From the [cleanup documentation](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-cleanup.html),

> **Refresh shell overlays**
>
> Sometimes the shell overlays, especially on the tree view on the left side of the explorer don't show the current status, or the status cache failed to recognize changes. In this situation, you can use this command to force a refresh.

**Update 2:** This can be automated in 1.7 using `TortoiseProc.exe` and Client Side Hook Scripts.  I often run into inconsistent status after a commit, so I added a post-commit hook script wrapping the following command into a batch file called `refresh_shell.bat`,

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:cleanup /nodlg /noui /refreshshell /pathfile:%1
```

(The batch file is necessary to accept the argument to the temp file containing the paths that were committed.)

Note also when configuring the hook script that the working copy path is the directory tree that the hook is enabled for.

See [Automating TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html) for more on using `TortoiseProc.exe` and [TortoiseSVN's Settings](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html) for more on Client Side Hook Scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. In my experience, using the command with /path:%6 works better than with /pathfile:%1 though. The command becomes then : "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:cleanup /nodlg /noui /refreshshell /path:%6

Answer (score 2):

Close and open explorer window doesn't help. Kill the TSVNCache.exe process helps.